# com.samsung.android.content.clipboard.SemClipboardManager.registerClipboardEventListener + 708 (SemClipboardManager.java:708)

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile

After Android Pie update I am facing a samsung specific issue only in J7, J7 Neo and J7 Pro models related to semclipboard samsung code and I am not able to reproduce it.

This issue was not happening before only after the Android update and here is the log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getOpPackageName()' on a null object reference
com.samsung.android.content.clipboard.SemClipboardManager.registerClipboardEventListener + 708 (SemClipboardManager.java:708)
android.widget.EditText.updateClipboardFilter + 322 (EditText.java:322)
android.widget.EditText.onFocusChanged + 262 (EditText.java:262)
android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal + 7694 (View.java:7694)
android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch + 12386 (View.java:12386)
android.view.View.requestFocus + 12360 (View.java:12360)
android.view.View.requestFocus + 12327 (View.java:12327)
android.view.View.requestFocus + 12269 (View.java:12269)
android.view.View.onTouchEvent + 15324 (View.java:15324)
android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent + 11274 (TextView.java:11274)
android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent + 13473 (View.java:13473)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3222 (ViewGroup.java:3222)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2904 (ViewGroup.java:2904)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3222 (ViewGroup.java:3222)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2904 (ViewGroup.java:2904)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3222 (ViewGroup.java:3222)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2904 (ViewGroup.java:2904)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3222 (ViewGroup.java:3222)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2904 (ViewGroup.java:2904)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3222 (ViewGroup.java:3222)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2904 (ViewGroup.java:2904)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3222 (ViewGroup.java:3222)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2904 (ViewGroup.java:2904)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3222 (ViewGroup.java:3222)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2904 (ViewGroup.java:2904)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3222 (ViewGroup.java:3222)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2904 (ViewGroup.java:2904)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3222 (ViewGroup.java:3222)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2904 (ViewGroup.java:2904)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3222 (ViewGroup.java:3222)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2904 (ViewGroup.java:2904)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3222 (ViewGroup.java:3222)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2904 (ViewGroup.java:2904)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent + 734 (DecorView.java:734)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent + 1880 (PhoneWindow.java:1880)
android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent + 3489 (Activity.java:3489)
android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent + 69 (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent + 692 (DecorView.java:692)
android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent + 13721 (View.java:13721)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent + 6200 (ViewRootImpl.java:6200)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess + 5978 (ViewRootImpl.java:5978)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver + 5427 (ViewRootImpl.java:5427)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext + 5480 (ViewRootImpl.java:5480)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward + 5446 (ViewRootImpl.java:5446)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward + 5605 (ViewRootImpl.java:5605)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply + 5454 (ViewRootImpl.java:5454)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply + 5662 (ViewRootImpl.java:5662)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver + 5427 (ViewRootImpl.java:5427)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext + 5480 (ViewRootImpl.java:5480)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward + 5446 (ViewRootImpl.java:5446)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply + 5454 (ViewRootImpl.java:5454)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver + 5427 (ViewRootImpl.java:5427)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent + 8504 (ViewRootImpl.java:8504)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents + 8424 (ViewRootImpl.java:8424)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent + 8377 (ViewRootImpl.java:8377)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent + 8619 (ViewRootImpl.java:8619)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent + 198 (InputEventReceiver.java:198)
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
android.os.MessageQueue.next + 326 (MessageQueue.java:326)
android.os.Looper.loop + 181 (Looper.java:181)
android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7156 (ActivityThread.java:7156)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 494 (RuntimeInit.java:494)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 975 (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

I think it could be related to copy and pasting text. The screen where it is being thrown is a passcode activity which is supposed to avoid this operation.

The exception is thrown around fourth or fifth line of this code

```
@OnClick(R.id.root_view)
public void onRootViewClick() {
    if (mInput != null) {
        mInput.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mInput.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if(inputMethodManager != null)
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(mInput, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

Are someone facing the same issue? I don't know how to reproduce or fix it. I only have a Samsung J7 (2016) model which has not Android Pie support from Samsung.

Comment: Hi I to am getting the same with my app on certain samsung models it is on focus of the edittext. I have tried many things. I am speaking the them and they have sent me here

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. In my case, the problem was that once when I tested my app using [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary), I find out about very specific kind of leak in Samsung mobiles and found a solution for it [here](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/740#issuecomment-374115077). So in my `Application` class, I added this code:

```
private final class LeakPreventionLifecycleCallbacks implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("samsung")) {
                    Object systemService = getSystemService(Class.forName("com.samsung.android.content.clipboard.SemClipboardManager"));
                    Field mContext = systemService.getClass().getDeclaredField("mContext");
                    mContext.setAccessible(true);
                    mContext.set(systemService, null);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { //ignored }

            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }
```

And now in android 9 update of J7 mobiles this code causes a crash in every focus change event of edit texts. By removing this callback everything is back to normal

Comment: Thank you, this has indeed fix the problem with crash on focus, however I now have the memory leak. Have asked Samsung to fix the leak or provided us with a solution for both

Comment: You're welcome:) Yes we have to choose one between leak and crash for now

Comment: It will be easier for understanding for newbies if you'll add description of adding it in 
 Application. Like `this.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(LeakPreventionLifecycleCallbacks());`. Thanks.